# FluentValidation: validator without property

Tags: .net, fluentvalidation

I have a case where if you have some settings in **app.config**, a Validator should always fail with some message (no matter of any property values). Is there a clean way to do this?

Right now I am using this code:

```
RuleFor(x => x.SomeRandomProperty).Must(srp => false).WithMessage("My message");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `Validate` like this to check if the value exist and return a custom `ValidationResult` or stick to how you've done it above.

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(Person instance)
{

    if(ValueIsInConfigFile)
        return new ValidationResult(new List<ValidationFailure>(){new ValidationFailure("SomeProperty", "There is a value in the config file which made this fail")});
    return base.Validate(instance);//Will apply your normal Rules
}
```

Steve